# Import alternative stepper motor in my fritzing sketch

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I have a question, which is on the usage of [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/). I'm trying to sketch up a robot I have made. I want make a proper sketch, which I can send to a manufacture.

I found a stepper motor used in this [sketch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56212/have-i-missed-something-when-connecting-this-stepper-motor). I cannot find the same stepper motor in the core package of components, that is default with the Fritzing download.

Could someone tell my were to find these extra components and how to import them into Fritzing?

I know the question is not directly about electrical engineering, but I consider it to be an important part, so I still ask the question here!

Comment: If it's not on the Fritzing site then we don't have it.

Comment: "On the fritzing site?" - It's not part of the download package, but I have seen other use it. I looked at this [site](https://code.google.com/p/fritzing/issues/detail?id=2753) , but can't find it there. Could there be some other place to find it and import it?

Comment: We don't know. If it were then we'd use Google to find it.

Comment: I did try that first, but didn't manage to do so. I thought that there might be some library or import packages that I didn't know of, since I can see other people use them, as the one I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new parts in Fritzing is quite easy - just choose the "Import.." options from the menu in the parts bin. You would be looking for a *.fzbz file to load. And when all else fails, its actually not to hard to create your own part (hardest part is navigating the documentation).

But first you need something to import of course. The stepper motor you linked to looks similar to ones that go by various manufacturer part numbers, like the [Adafruit #858](http://www.adafruit.com/product/858). Another common unit is the `28BYJ-48` - just google that and you'll find many suppliers.

Then find the Fritzing parts. Adafruit have stepper motor part in the [Adafruit Fritzing library](https://github.com/adafruit/Fritzing-Library). That may be close to your actual unit, but I think the wiring is different to the 28BYJ-48.

To get the wiring correct, I actually made my own 28BYJ-48; it's available in the [X113647Stepper](https://github.com/tardate/X113647Stepper) repo on GitHub (along with a part for the X113647 stepper driver board, which is also quite common but I hadn't found elsewhere).

[image: X113647 and 28BYJ-48]

Comment: That's exactly the kind of information I needed. I was about to dig in to Eagle, but think the amount of time needed to get familiar with Eagle is to demanding for my needs.

Comment: hth Tommy. Good luck with the robot!